# Java parse text to integer

Tags: java, numberformatexception

How do I parse a text value into integer in Java ?

I have tried below 2 things;

```
Integer.valueOf("22,959");
Integer.parseInt("22,959");
```

But I am getting NumberFormatException with both.

Just to add, the text is dynamic, but would be in the comma format that i have given as example.

Comment: One option would be to strip the string of comma.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class

```
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    format.parse(num).intValue();
```

This default instance will be as per your default Locale.
You can get instance according to the Locale by

```
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.UK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the options are correct. `valueOf` returns a `new Integer()` object, while `parseInt` returns a primitive `int`.

However, your problem is with the comma, not with the method itself. So just do a

```
String value = "22,959";
value.replace(",", "");
Integer.valueOf(value);
Integer.parseInt(value);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have data with separators, you could use `NumberFormat` with locale

ie `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).parse("22,959")`

Answer (score 0):

Integer as mentioned in this name, only accept integer numbers. Means only number without dot o decimal separator. for removing decimal separator you can use `replace` or `replaceAll` methods for your string:

```
Integer.parseInt("22,959".replaceAll(",",""));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the comma first :

`Integer.valueOf("22,959".replaceAll(",", ""));`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you remove the comma with

```
Integer.parseInt("22,959".replaceAll(",", ""));
```

This assumes that you are definitely not going to ever have to deal with European locales, like Portuguese where they use decimal for number separation and comma for fractions.

if you want to cope with alternative locales, you'll need to parse the String using Numberformat:

To format a number for the current Locale, use one of the factory class methods:

```
myString = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(myNumber);
```

To format a number for a different Locale, specify it in the call to getInstance.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
```

Then you just:

```
myNumber = nf.parse(myString);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to parse float number, not Integer. Integer number should not have any decimal separator. Should look like Integer.parseInt("22");
For your case should look like: float f = Float.parseFloat("22,959");

Comment: It's probably an integer with comma as thousand separator.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @primitivwurzel, Integer cannot have decimal. Use Double.parseDouble()/Double.valueOf() instead of Integer.parseInt()/Integer.valueOf()

plus, Decimal point separated by dot (.), not comma (,)